# Access WMI instances via MI without WS-Management service

Tags: c#, .net, windows, wmi

I'm trying to access WMI classes on Windows 7 and Windows 10 Embedded on localhost via the Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure API from C#.
It works using the code from the below snippet, but only if I start the Windows Remote Management (WS-Management) service.

I noticed that I can access the classes via Powershell cmdlets like Get-WmiObject even when the WS-Management service is not started. Is there any way to access WMI without the service started via the Microsoft Management Infrastructure APIs?

```
CimSession cimSession = CimSession.Create("localhost");
IEnumerable<CimInstance> enumeratedInstances = cimSession.EnumerateInstances(@"root\cimv2", "Win32_Process");
foreach (CimInstance cimInstance in enumeratedInstances)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", cimInstance.CimInstanceProperties[ "Name" ].Value.ToString());
}
```

Comment: I think the mistake here is that you're passing `"localhost"` as a hostname. To connect to the same machine, you should instead pass `null`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, I came accross the same issue. To add to this, Windows.Management.Instrumentation is not available in .NET Core, but Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure is.

With the help of a lot of Googling, I finally found the options that work. It seems that to setup a local session, you have to use DCOM session options.

Here is the code that worked for me:

```
var sessionOptions = new DComSessionOptions
{
    Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)
};
var cimSession = CimSession.Create("localhost", sessionOptions);

var volumes = cimSession.QueryInstances(@"root\cimv2", "WQL", "SELECT * FROM Win32_Volume");

foreach (var volume in volumes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(volume.CimInstanceProperties["Name"].Value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are workin locally then you should always be able to access WMI. From the MSDN documentation:

> WMI runs as a service with the display name "Windows Management
>   Instrumentation" and the service name "winmgmt". WMI runs
>   automatically at system startup under the LocalSystem account. If WMI
>   is not running, it automatically starts when the first management
>   application or script requests connection to a WMI namespace.

You can also use [ORMi](https://github.com/nicoriff/ORMi) (very simple to use) library for WMI for automatic mapping between WMI classes and C# models.

```
[WMIClass("Win32_Process")]
public class Process
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Then querying:

```
WMIHelper helper = new WMIHelper("root\\CimV2");

List<Process> process = helper.Query<Process>().ToList();
```

Comment: So since the "Windows Management Instrumentation" service is running and above mentioned PS cmdlets like Get-WmiObject are working, it looks like the cmdlets are using this service. Then the question is more whether I can use the local WMI service instead of the remote management service by using the classes in the namespace Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.

Comment: Yes you can. Try Windows.Management.Instrumentation namespace

Comment: So System.Management.Instrumentation should be used? According to https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/26601, MS.Management.Infrastructure is the preferred way: "On Windows, we recommend using Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure namespace (aka WMIv2). System.Managmeent (aka WMIv1) is deprecated", but I'll try this one.